# Why JEST mock module's async function does not need async or assertion or resolves

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs

All,

I am new to Jest, the [Testing Async Code section](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/asynchronous) has made enough confuses to me, it provides so many ways to handle same case:

```
[1] done()
[2] expect.assertions(1) + return Promise
[3] expect.assertions(1) + return expect.resolves
[4] async callback +  await + NO return expect
```

And the thing even more confuse is when I get to [Mock Functions section](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions):

[The mock module section:](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions#mocking-modules)

```
//users.test.js
import axios from 'axios';
import Users from './users';

jest.mock('axios');

test('should fetch users', () => {
  const resp = {data: [{name: 'Bob'}]};
  axios.get.mockResolvedValue(resp);

  // or you could use the following depending on your use case:
  // axios.get.mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve(resp))

  return Users.all().then(users => expect(users).toEqual(resp.data));
});
```

I wonder which way of those 4 ways is used here? Any detail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The test is [returning a `Promise`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/asynchronous#promises).

That corresponds to `[2] expect.assertions(1) + return Promise`.

Just note that you only need to use `expect.assertions` if you expect the `Promise` to reject and are using a `catch`:

> If you expect a promise to be rejected use the .catch method. Make sure to add expect.assertions to verify that a certain number of assertions are called. Otherwise a fulfilled promise would not fail the test.

If the `Promise` is expected to resolve then you can do your assertions in a `then` like in the code sample and simply return the resulting `Promise`:

> Just return a promise from your test, and Jest will wait for that promise to resolve. If the promise is rejected, the test will automatically fail.

Comment: Thanks, could you tell where that assertions gets made?

Comment: Yes, the assertion is made in the `then` in the code sample: `expect(users).toEqual(resp.data)`.  `Jest` will wait until the `Promise` resolves which includes the `then` which will run the `expect` assertion.

Comment: Sorry, do you mean it does not need to explicitly use expect.assertions(1) in the code?

Comment: Ah, I get what you are asking.  Yes `expect.assertions(1)` is not needed.  Calling `expect.assertions` tells `Jest` to fail the test if the expected number of `expect` statements don't end up running.  You can add it if you want, but it isn't needed since if `Users.all()` fails the test will fail, and if `resp.data` does not equal `users` the test will fail.  `expect.assertions` is only really needed in something like the rejected `Promise`/`catch` scenario where you have to make sure the `expect` statement in the `catch` actually ran.

Comment: Thanks, so this only work when use mock function, if it is a real function then the promise can not be waited by jest?

Comment: A `Promise` can be returned from *any* test and `Jest` will wait for the `Promise` to resolve before determining if the test passed or failed.

Comment: Get it, as long as I RETURN that promise, JEST will wait. Thanks!